# MediaWiki's Minerva mobile skin is not showing MediaWiki:Loginprompt

Tags: mediawiki

To link new users from Special:Login to Special:RequestAccount I'm using a Message in the MediaWiki:Loginprompt page.
In the default Vector skin it gets shown when logging in, also in the pivot skin, but not when using the mobile MinervaNeue skin, activated with:

```
wfLoadSkin( 'MinervaNeue' );
$wgMFDefaultSkinClass = 'SkinMinerva';
```

in LocalSettings.php

Is there a way to show MediaWiki:Loginprompt in Minerva skin or another way of refering users to Special:RequestAccount?

Comment: You could use the `uselang=qqx` URL parameter to find out what system messages are showing on the page instead of your desired `loginprompt` message , you could than change the displayed message to show the `loginpromot` message content, example url:
https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=MediaWiki&returntoquery=useskin%3Dminerva&uselang=qqx

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find all the messages used on the Minerva login page

https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?useskin=minerva&title=Special:UserLogin&uselang=qqx

You could add the desired message to one of the used messages.

For example add this to the bottom of the `MediaWiki:Mobile-frontend-generic-login-new` page to transclude the desired loginprompt message in that message

`{{:MediaWiki:Loginprompt}}`